# Python Selenium send_keys to email input field

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make an auto-checkout script on https://www.footish.se/sneakers/fila-wmns-disruptor-run-1010866-60m

I have made it to the checkout page, but unable to enter my email in the "email" input-field.

The code looks like this

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/label/div/div/input")
email.send_keys("test@email.com")
```

Have implemented some sort of function to wait for the desired elements untill they are loaded in. One example->

```
while not find:
try:
find = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[10]/div[1]/h2")
print("Loaded info")
except:
continue
```

The error i am getting is this.
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/span/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div/label/div/div/input"}`

How would i resolve this? Thanks in advance....

Comment: That just means the element is not present on the page. Use `implicit wait` to wait for it to appear and loaded into the DOM

Comment: I used `driver.implicitly_wait(5)`, but its still unable to locate the xpath.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `email` field is a dynamicallly generated element and so when a check is initially made it is not yet present. You may try and use the `until` method to wait for a specific time and see if it indeed does get applied to the `DOM`.

Sample code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")) # set your id here
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Do update if it doesn't work. It's then likely to do with frame or wrong path issues.

Comment: Solved it using this 'driver.switch_to.frame('klarna-checkout-iframe')', apparently when inside an iFrame your have to switch into it. Only way for me to get it to work.